# Simple Animations oh Html Page

Tags: jquery, flash, html, animation

I am looking to make website that has multiple animations on it for example when website is opened after some random delay a burger appears and starts running or after some time french fries pop out from bottom.

now the question is

1.What technology should be used to develop animations (Flash or JQuery can be used)?

2.As we have to do things on client side how we can manage events to happen after some delay (Javascript or something else)?

3.How to make images or animations independent so that they can move over existing html website and not disturb their layout?

Thanks

Comment: Is target browser also specific? For example flash won't work on an iPad/iPod. I would suggest jQuery

Comment: Here's the gig: Flash isn't supported in Apple products; so you rape yourself in the smartphone market. JavaScript isn't enabled on all computers, so you hurt yourself there, as well. HTML5/CSS3 have *amazing* animation options as well; but you can only target newer browsers/devices with that. You most likely want a solid mix of both jQuery/HTML5 and, following standard practices, a still-frame solution for older browsers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery because no additional plugins required for client
2. On client side you can call js functions after page loaded and 10 sec passed like this. Suppose you have hidden (style="display:none;") div with id = hiddenFriedBurger

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(showHiddenBurger(),10000);//time in ms
   });

   function showHiddenBurger(){
       jQuery("#hiddenFriedBurger").show();
   }
3. You should make css style="position:absolute;" or smth like that and to overlap html elements add css property "z-index:1;" or greater index.

p.s. for 2 second question you need to learn more about setTimeout and setInterval just google it and sorry for src formatting i am newbie at stack overflow